# get the amount from a price period table

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

I have a table price period `tblPricePeriod` in which I have the `Amount` to be charged between two dates for a particular apartment.

I have also `StartDate` and `EndDate` columns for the price period with `ApartmentId`.

Below is the structure of my table:

[image]

Now I want to calculate to charge the total amount for days of booking.

For example, if someone stays from 4feb to 7 feb then he has to pay according to following scheme:

```
4-     10
5-     10
6-     10  
7    -     nothing as this is checkout date 
-----------------------------------------------------
totamt--- 30$
```

I have `startdate` and `enddate` and `apartmentid` as parameter, I am using ms access db.

Now I am using c# code to traverse this with follow code but not successed.

I am getting the amount for all the dates one by one and adding them in one global variable.

**The code is as follows:**

```
decimal amount = 0;

// loop to traverse all days between start date and end date 
for (DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate); d < Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate); d = d.AddDays(1))
{
    string priceCalc = "select Amount from tblPricePeriod where ApartmentId=" + ApartmenId + " and cdate(StartDate) <='" + d.ToShortDateString() + "' and cdate(EndDate) >= '" + d.ToShortDateString() + "'";
    DataSet dsPriceCalc = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Connection.ConnectionString, CommandType.Text, priceCalc);
    if (dsPriceCalc.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        amount = amount + Convert.ToDecimal(dsPriceCalc.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Amount"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is? Are you getting an error or the wrong summation? Also, if you don't want the customer to pay for the checkout date then you should use `>` instead of `>=` at the checkout date.

Comment: wrong simulation no data come from query and amout stay zero

Comment: Those 'StartDate' and 'EndDate' columns, do they have a 'date' type? And didn't Access need '#' delimiters for dates?

Comment: Could you try to locate the problem? Does the `priceCalc`, `dsPriceCalc` or `amount` contain any data?

Comment: yes they have data as i tried the quick watch with debugger

Comment: Debug your code and copy sql statement, then execute sql script in access sql editor, then check whether return result or not. If no result, likely critiera in date format is not working.

Comment: Unless you have tried with the correct delimiter, as shown by @HansKesting, there does not seem to be any point in trying other things.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the SUM Function in Sql:

```
SELECT SUM(salary) as "Total Salary"
FROM employees
WHERE salary > 25000;
```

//EDIT:

Instead of looping over your DateTimes you can select the Sum of the Amount directly:

```
DateTime dtStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate);
DateTime dtEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate); // maybe -1 day 

string priceCalc = "select SUM( Amount ) from tblPricePeriod where ApartmentId=" + ApartmenId + " and cdate(StartDate) <= '" + dtStartDate.ToShortDateString( ) + "' and cDate(EndDate) >= '" + dtEndDate.ToShortDateString( ) + "'";
```

Comment: @Viper Thit is correct if there are multiple records with startDate/ EndDate then it will fetch all the records.

Answer (score 0):

You could adopt an entirely SQL approach:

```
SELECT  SUM(TotalAmount) AS Amount
FROM    (   SELECT  Amount * (1 + DATEDIFF('d', @StartDate, EndDate))  AS TotalAmount,  
                    (1 + DATEDIFF('d', @StartDate, EndDate)) AS Days, 
                    Amount AS DailyRate
            FROM    tblPricePeriod
            WHERE   @StartDate >= StartDate
            AND     @StartDate <= EndDate
            AND     @EndDate > EndDate
            AND     ApartmentID = @ApartmentID
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  Amount * (DATEDIFF('d', @StartDate, @EndDate)),  DATEDIFF('d', @StartDate, @EndDate), Amount
            FROM    tblPricePeriod
            WHERE   @StartDate >= StartDate
            AND     @StartDate <= EndDate
            AND     @EndDate >= StartDate
            AND     @EndDate <= EndDate
            AND     ApartmentID = @ApartmentID
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  Amount * (1 + DATEDIFF('d', StartDate, EndDate)),  (1 + DATEDIFF('d', StartDate, EndDate)) , Amount
            FROM    tblPricePeriod
            WHERE   @StartDate < StartDate
            AND     @EndDate > EndDate
            AND     ApartmentID = @ApartmentID
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  Amount * (DATEDIFF('d', StartDate, @EndDate)),  DATEDIFF('d', StartDate, @EndDate) , Amount
            FROM    tblPricePeriod
            WHERE   @StartDate < StartDate
            AND     @EndDate <= EndDate
            AND     @EndDate > StartDate
            AND     ApartmentID = @ApartmentID
        ) AS Data
```

Since Access does not allow comments I've not neen able to annotate the query. The subquery has 4 parts, the top part is for when the Price Period End Date occurs during a visit, the second for when the visit falls entirely within 1 price period, the 3rd for when the visit crosses an entire price period, and the 4th for when the price period starts during a visit. Hope this is clear.

All you would then need to do is add the parameters @ApartmentID, @StartDate and @EndDate to your `ExecuteDataset` Method which is a better approach than concatenating strings anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  SUM(( 
    IIF(EndDate < @EndDate, EndDate, IIF(@EndDate < StartDate, StartDate, @EndDate)) -
    IIF(StartDate > @StartDate, StartDate, IIF(@StartDate > EndDate, EndDate, @StartDate))
  ) * Amount)
FROM tblPricePeriod
```

This takes the same sort of approach as GarethD. It's certainly shorter but you could argue which shows the intent clearer. I couldn't test this as I don't have access but I believe it has the IIF statement. The @EndDate parameter needs to be your end date - 1. So in your example I would pass @End Date = 6 Feb.

The IIF statements basically calculate the number of days that need to be counted within each period.

Comment: This was my first thought too, but for some reason Access returns “This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables”. Yet if you replace @StartDate with an actual date (#27/02/2012#) it runs fine. I could not figure this out, so went for the union approach as I was able to get this to work.